# Mostrar una imagen desde mysql con javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, handlebars.js

Tengo este proyecto en javascript con mysql y nodejs, necesito mostrar la imagen de un producto, dicha imagen es almacenada previamente en una base de datos, ¿Cómo puedo mostrarla en el formulario de inventario? Por ahora solo muestra un icono roto o el nombre de la imagen. El campo imagen es de tipo mediumblob en la base, acepto sugerencias si hay otra manera de almacenarlo para que se muestre. Adjunto código y capturas. Muchas gracias.

```
//Archivo productos.js

router.get('/', isLoggedIn, async (req, res) => {
    const productos = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM PRODUCTOS');
    res.render('productos/productos_list', { productos});
});
```

```
//Archivo productos_list.hbs
//Parte donde muestra lo que contienen los campos

{{#each productos}}

                  <tr class="text-center">
                                        <td>{{SKU}}</td>
                                        <td>{{PRODUCTO}}</td>
                                        <td>{{DESCRIPCION}}</td>
                                        <td>{{PRECIO}}</td>
                                        <td>{{NUM_CATEGORIA}}</td>
                                        <td><img src="{{IMAGEN}}"></td>
                                        <td>{{ULTIMA_ACTUALIZACION}}</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="/productos/productos_edit/{{ID_PRODUCTO}}" class="btn btn-info">EDITAR</a>
                                            <a href="/productos/delete/{{ID_PRODUCTO}}" class="btn btn-danger">ELIMINAR</a>
            
                                        </td>
                                </tr>
                            
                        </tbody>

                        {{/each}}
```

```
//Tabla de productos

CREATE TABLE PRODUCTOS(
ID_PRODUCTO int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
SKU VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
PRODUCTO VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
DESCRIPCION VARCHAR(700) NULL,
PRECIO FLOAT NOT NULL,
NUM_CATEGORIA int NOT NULL,
IMAGEN MEDIUMBLOB NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (NUM_CATEGORIA) REFERENCES CATEGORIA(ID_CATEGORIA),
ULTIMA_ACTUALIZACION TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
PRIMARY KEY (ID_PRODUCTO)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

[image: Muestra del formulario]

Comment: Como lo tengo en un proyecto, es de subir los archivos, o tenerlos en un folder en el servidor, y luego tener las rutas de las imagenes en la bd, entonces al hacer la query mandas a llamar la ruta del servidor, si tienes el codigo dentro de la bd, creo que te va consumir mucho espacio segun la cantidad de productos que tengas, pero se puede

Comment: ¿Y de que tipo debería ser el campo de imagen? y estaría bien si me dieras un ejemplo del muestreo, Gracias! Edito y pongo la tabla de productos de la base.

Comment: Guardando las rutas, tu API o query tendria que retonarla en algun campo que tu puedas despues manipular con JavaScript, por ejemplo esto: https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers?page=1&per_page=10